# MATLAB : Which location the MATLAB 2 C source code is generated

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I just ran a successful command to convert a MATLAB .m file to C source code

```
>>codegen -c abc.m
>>
```

However I see the ">>" prompt again after command has finished (no errors, warnigs reported)- I understand that my C source code has been created - but in which directory - I cannot find any file having .c extension.

Comment: It may be in " C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin ". MATLAB uses current folder directory, When it creates new file.

Comment: Well I found it - it creates another folder codegen in My Documents Matlab directory. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The codegen command produces a directory called `codegen` in the directory where it is run. You can customize where the generated code is placed with the `-d` option:

```
codegen foo -d C:\some\directory\name
```